# How to select a specific button tag inside of a class

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementsbytagname

I would like to make that when you click the button, the code should alert the name inside of a class move. But my code does not work correctly, and the console says "Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of undefined". Is there something wrong in my javascript code?? Thanks.

Part of my javascript code;

```
for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
                document.getElementsByClassName("moves")[0].getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[i].onclick
                = alert(document.getElementsByClassName("moves")[0].document.getElementsByClassName("move")[i].textContent);
}
```

Part of my HTML code;

```
<div class="moves">
          <button>
            <span class="move">a</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
          <button>
            <span class="move">b</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
          <button>
            <span class="move">c</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
          <button>
            <span class="move">d</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things to note:

1 - When you were passing an `alert()` to the click handler, it was being called immediately.  You need to wrap it in a function.

2 - Using `this`, you don't need to reselect the element from the very top, you can go from where you currently are in the scope.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

  document.getElementsByClassName("moves")[0].getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[i].onclick = function() {
    alert(this.textContent.trim())
  };
}
```

```html
<div class="moves">
  <button>
            <span class="move">a</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
  <button>
            <span class="move">b</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
  <button>
            <span class="move">c</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
  <button>
            <span class="move">d</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! but the console still says "Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined"...

Comment: @AndyAnderson It's telling you that when you run it here? I'm not getting any console errors.

Comment: I made a typo there, and your code worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two choices:

1. You can get a `NodeList` of all of the buttons via `querySelectorAll(".moves button")`, then add event handlers to each of them,

   or
2. Use event delegation: Put the handler on the `.moves` element and then when the click occurs, see if it passed through a button and if so which one.

Here's #1:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".moves button").forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(this.textContent.trim());
    });
});
```

or

```
document.querySelectorAll(".moves button").forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", ({currentTarget: {textContent}}) => {
        console.log(textContent.trim());
    });
});
```

Live:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".moves button").forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", ({currentTarget: {textContent}}) => {
        console.log(textContent.trim());
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="moves">
  <button>
            <span class="move">a</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
  <button>
            <span class="move">b</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
  <button>
            <span class="move">c</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
  <button>
            <span class="move">d</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
</div>
```

Here's #2:

```
document.querySelector(".moves").addEventListener("click", ({target, currentTarget}) => {
    // From the element where the click occurred, find the ancestor matching `"button"`
    const btn = target.closest("button");
    // If we found one and it's inside `.moves` (not in the parent of `.moves`, though
    // that's not likely in this case), it's the button we want
    if (btn && currentTarget.contains(btn)) {
        console.log(btn.textContent.trim());
    }
});
```

Live:

```js
document.querySelector(".moves").addEventListener("click", ({target, currentTarget}) => {
    // From the element where the click occurred, find the ancestor matching `"button"`
    const btn = target.closest("button");
    // If we found one and it's inside `.moves` (not in the parent of `.moves`, though
    // that's not likely in this case), it's the button we want
    if (btn && currentTarget.contains(btn)) {
        console.log(btn.textContent.trim());
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="moves">
  <button>
            <span class="move">a</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
  <button>
            <span class="move">b</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
  <button>
            <span class="move">c</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
  <button>
            <span class="move">d</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
</div>
```